# Content added by load() function dissapears after ajax action

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, load

I am creating a sorting page, which will show content of database, and the user can sort it with listjs. Problem is that when i press any button, the content loaded from the database disappears. When I fill the content manually it works great. Can anybody please help me with this problem?

My load function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".list").load("../wp-content/php/sorting.php");
});
```

sorting.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("***", "***", "**") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("***");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM business");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 ?><li class="onebusiness"><a href="<?php
  echo $row['link'];?>"><img src="<?php
  echo $row['img'];?>" height="125" width="125"/><p class="name"><?php
  echo $row['name'];?></p><p class="category" style="display:none;"><?php
  echo $row['category'];?></p></a></li><?php
  }
mysql_close();
?>
```

HTML:

```
<script src="../wp-content/js/filter/call-php.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../wp-content/js/list/list-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="busineseslist">
    <input class="search" placeholder="Search Business" />
    <ul class="sort-by">
        <li class="sort btn" data-sort="name">Sort by name</li>
        <li class="sort btn" data-sort="category">Sort by category</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="filter">
        <li class="btn" id="filter-none">Show all</li>
        <li class="btn" id="filter-something">Only show something</li>
        <li class="btn" id="filter-else">Only show something else</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="list"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that all `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Probably means you're not getting the content in the form you're expecting it. Output it to console.log and see what shows up.

Comment: how could i output code to console?

Comment: You should include in every button js action this line at the end: $(".list").load("../wp-content/php/sorting.php");

Comment: That would be good idea, but wordpress dont support php in pages or posts so its need to be added with JS

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont just do this:

```
<script src="../wp-content/js/filter/call-php.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../wp-content/js/list/list-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="busineseslist">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search Business" />
<ul class="sort-by">
    <li class="sort btn" data-sort="name">Sort by name</li>
    <li class="sort btn" data-sort="category">Sort by category</li>
</ul>
<ul class="filter">
    <li class="btn" id="filter-none">Show all</li>
    <li class="btn" id="filter-something">Only show something</li>
    <li class="btn" id="filter-else">Only show something else</li>
</ul>
<div class="list"><?php include '../wp-content/php/sorting.php'; ?></div>
</div>
```

With this you can delete this line:

```
<script src="../wp-content/js/filter/call-php.js" type="text/javascript"></script>//delete this
```

Which i think its the js with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".list").load("../wp-content/php/sorting.php");
});
```

Because with the php include you dont need the load function ;)

------------------------EDITED----------------------------------------

In wordpress, you can include files in this way:

Put the include files in your theme folder and use this in your theme's footer.php:

```
 <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sorting.php'); ?>
```

See this reference link: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/wordpress-include-template-files.html

Your div should looks like:

Go to the 'Theme Editor', look for the file that generates the html. Edit it and place this code between the divs tags:

```
<div class="list"><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sorting.php'); ?></div>
```

Saludos.

Comment: With this you can get rid of the load function ;)

Comment: That would be good idea, but wordpress dont support php in pages or posts so its need to be added with JS

Comment: this works, but it places loaded content to footer a need it in list div

Comment: i thought you wanted me to insert this to footer, now you want me to insert it into html, where php dont work. i am sorry if i get it all wrong but could you be more specific?